# How to create an APIs which will return the list of rows from a file which is a large CSV file stored in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, batch-processing

I need help to get a code in form of 4 REST API in java spring boot

1. API that will read large csv file(Size ~1GB) stored in AWS s3 and return the data in chunks when request is made to the rest API.
2. API to Update this large CSV file stored in S3 from rendered data by first API
3. API to Export this large CSV file in .xlsx format
4. API to Update this large CSV file via exported .xlsx upload.

I have written the code but that is working fine for small size CSV files but for large files is giving heap memory out of bound and gateway timeouts.

Please suggest some faster and efficent way to achieve this without getting gateway timeout and heap memory issues..

Tried various ways of achieving it most of time facing heap memory issue and gateway timeout as system is taking long time to process.

No Idea how to achieve it via batch processing or processing in chunks without data loss.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.